# Kid called Roland who wanted to win a grocery competition to win a house

Tags: identification-request

I grew up in Australia in the 90’s/2000’s and am trying to find a children’s book. It’s about a family of extreme couponers/competitors and their son Roland who is trying to win a house from a grocery store competition. Certain grocery items have a letter inside the label, and he needs to collect a certain amount of these letters to win. I think the letters spelled out something.

Comment: Hi welcome to Literature stack exchange : you’ve provided helpful pointers re content of your book , additional help with the appearance , cover art , publisher , dates ( when you read , when it was published ) are helpful . Sherlock Holmes was won’t to say “ omit no detail however slight “ this does apply here too .This wiki is helpful with regard to info to include literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info